# Combine Mongo Output with Node for API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express, keystonejs

I''m really new to Node but I currently have a NodeJS / Express open source CMS and would like to output some API data for an app that I am working. Forgive me if I'm not using the correct terminology or whatnot, this is new to me.

What I currently have are two collections, locations and tours. The CMS allows me to create a relationship between the two. This simply stores an array of ObjectID's in the locations record for each associated tour record.

What I want to do is take my API output code (below) and have it output the entire tours array, complete with all the fields (title, description, etc), in with each location record. Currently it only outputs an array of the ID's.

Here is my current code:

```
var async = require('async'),
 landmark = require('keystone');

var Location = keystone.list('Location'),
        Tour = keystone.list('Tour');

    /**
     * List Locations
     */
    exports.list = function(req, res) {
        Location.model.find(function(err, items) {

            if (err) return res.apiError('database error', err);

            res.apiResponse({
                locations: items
            });

        });
    }

    /**
     * Get Location by ID
     */
    exports.get = function(req, res) {
        Location.model.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, item) {

            if (err) return res.apiError('database error', err);
            if (!item) return res.apiError('not found');

            res.apiResponse({
                location: item
            });

        });
    }
```

Current API output (truncated):

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "_id": "53a47997ebe91d8a4a26d251",
      "slug": "test-location",
      "lastModified": "2014-06-20T20:19:14.484Z",
      "commonName": "test location",
      "__v": 3,
      "url": "",
      "tours": [
        "53a47963ebe91d8a4a26d250"
      ],
      "images": []
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'm looking for:

```
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "_id": "53a47997ebe91d8a4a26d251",
      "slug": "test-location",
      "lastModified": "2014-06-20T20:19:14.484Z",
      "commonName": "test location",
      "__v": 3,
      "url": "",
      "tours": [
        {
           "_id": "53a47963ebe91d8a4a26d250",
           "title": "my test tour title",
           "url": "url_to_audio_file"
        }
      ],
      "images": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyone know if this is possible? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like you have setup your `Location` model to have a reference to the `Tour`s, defined as an array of `Tour`s.  This means that when you store the `Tour` within your `Location`, you're not storing the data that represents that `Tour`, but instead an ID that references the `Tour`.  When you perform the `find` operation, you're seeing that in the response that you send back to the client.

If this is the case, then you might want to take a look at [Mongoose's `populate` function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).  This will take those references and populate them fully with the data that they contain.

So for instance, you can change your query to the following:

```
Location.model.find().populate('tours').exec(function(err, items) {
    // items should now contain fully populated tours
}
```

Let me know if this isn't what you mean and I can try to help further.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I posted this question on another forum as well and they suggested the same thing, however it's not working. You are correct in what you assumed I had my `Location` model to reference `Tour`. Here is how I reference `Tour` in the `Location` model: `Location.relationship({ path: 'tours', ref: 'Tour', refPath: 'location' });`. `populate` doesn't seem to work though. Here is my updated code to try and get the tours out:

`Location.model.findById(req.params.id).populate({path: 'tours', ref: 'Tour'}).exec(function(err, item) {
 res.apiResponse({
  location: item
 });
});`

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @dylants is absolutely correct. However, for it to work you need to have `tours` declared as a `Types.Relationship` field in your `Location` list with the `ref` option set to `Tour`.

Check out the Keystone docs on [Relationship Fields](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#relationship-fields).

I included the `many`: `true` option in my example below, because I assumed this is a one-to-many relationship. If it isn't, you can discard it.

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
  Location = keystone.list('Location');

Location.add({
   ...
   tours: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Tour', many: true },
   ...
});
```

The `List.relationship()` method you mentioned is meant to be used only if you want a list of related documents to automatically appear in the `Keystone Admin UI`, and not to establish the actual relationship.

Hope this helps.